# Does antimagic field affect Gem Flight?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, racial-traits, antimagic-field

***Gem Flight, Fizban's Treasure of Dragons, pg. 11***

> You can use a bonus action to manifest spectral wings for 1 minute.
> For the duration, you gain a flying speed equal to your walking speed
> and can hover. Once you use this trait, you can’t do so again until
> you finish a long rest.

From the Sage Advice Compedium, I'm trying to answer these questions to determine if the feature is magical:

> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
>   Does its description say it’s magical?

I believe an argument can be made that the word "spectral" implies magic. I just wish the game were more clear about these issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It does not, but your DM might decide otherwise

The text maybe *implies* magic because the wings are spectral, but it does not *say* the wings are magical. So by a strict reading of the criterium "**Does its description *say* it is magical**" the feature is not magical and will not be suppressed by *Antimagic Field*.

For example, the cold breath of an white dragon also feels very magical, but is not. The SAC tries to justify this as follows:

> You might be thinking, “Dragons seem pretty magical to me.” And yes, they are extraordinary! Their description even says they’re magical. But our game makes a distinction between two types of magic
>
> - the **background magic that is part of the D&D multiverse’s physics and the physiology of many D&D creatures**
> - the concentrated magical energy that is contained in a magic item or channeled to create a spell or other focused magical effect

By that logic, spectral wings are just part of the physiology of the creature, "background magic".

To be honest, I feel this is lame and arbitrary. But at least, there are clear rules to follow to draw the line.

The game's language is not unclear here. It just leads to a result that is not what one would intuitively like it to be.

And that's why we rely on the DM to apply judgement. If a DM does not like this outcome, and decides that "In my game, by gosh, an antimagic field will supress your dainty spectral wings!", the DMG on page 4 gives them the right to rule so:

> The D&D rules help you and the other players have
> a good time, but the rules aren't in charge. You're the DM, and you are in charge of the game.